# проблемы stm32 uart

Tags: c++, stm32

Всем привет. Возникла небольшая проблема. Начал осваивать STM32. пытаюсь посылать символы по UART взял в качестве примера этот код:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h" 

void Init(void); //Объявление функции инициализации GPIOA и USART1
void Transmit(char); //Объявление функции передачи одиночного символа

int main()
{
  Init(); //Вызов функции инициализации
  while(1)
  {
    Transmit('S'); //Вызов  функции передачи одиночного символа
    Transmit('T');
    Transmit('M');
    Transmit('3');
    Transmit('2');
    Transmit('F');
    Transmit('1');
    Transmit('0');
    Transmit('3');
    Transmit('\r'); //Перевод позиции печати в крайнее левое положение
    Transmit('\n'); //Перевод позиции печати на новую строку
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<0x000FFFFF; i++); //Временная задержка
  }
}

void Init()
{
  //RCC
  RCC->APB2ENR |= (RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN | RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN); //Включаем тактирование GPIOA и USART1
  //GPIOA
  GPIOA->CRH |= (GPIO_CRH_CNF9_1 | GPIO_CRH_MODE9); //GPIOA - выход Push_Pull, альтернативная функция, скорость 50 МГц
  //USART1
  USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE; //Включаем USART1
  USART1->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_M; //Размерность слова данных - 8 бит
  USART1->CR2 &= ~USART_CR2_STOP; //1 стоп-бит
  USART1->BRR = 0x34D; //Скорость обмена 9600 бод
  USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE; //Включаем передатчик USART1  
}

void Transmit(char data)
{
  while(!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TC)); //Проверка завершения передачи предыдущих данных
  USART1->DR = data; //Передача данных
}
```

Компилируется без ошибок зашиваю в контроллер. На переходнике usb-uart слабо мигает светодиод. Т.е. что-то шлется. Но программа терминал на компе показывает, что ничего не приходит. Пытался смотреть через разные терминалы - одно и то же - ничего не приходит. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос снят, нужно было верно выставить скорость UART, она зависит от тактовой частоты.